# Binding one dependency property to another

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a custom Tab Control that I have created, but I am having an issue. I have an Editable TextBox as part of the custom TabControl View.

```
<Controls:EditableTextControl x:Name="PageTypeName" 
                                  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type Controls:EditableTextControl}}" Grid.Row="0" TabIndex="0" 
                                  Uid="0"
                                  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="PageTypeNameTextBox"
                                  AutomationProperties.Name="PageTypeName"
                                  Visibility="{Binding ElementName=PageTabControl,Path=ShowPageType}">
        <Controls:EditableTextControl.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Name="TabContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="Rename Page Type" Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.EnterEditMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" 
                          AutomationProperties.AutomationId="RenamePageTypeMenuItem"
                          AutomationProperties.Name="RenamePageType"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete Page Type" Command="{Binding Path=PageTypeDeletedCommand}" 
                          AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DeletePageTypeMenuItem"
                          AutomationProperties.Name="DeletePageType"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Controls:EditableTextControl.ContextMenu>
        <Controls:EditableTextControl.Content>
            <!--<Binding Path="CurrentPageTypeViewModel.Name" Mode="TwoWay"/>-->
            <Binding ElementName="PageTabControl" Path="CurrentPageTypeName" Mode ="TwoWay"/>
        </Controls:EditableTextControl.Content>
    </Controls:EditableTextControl>
```

In the Content section I am binding to a Dependency Prop called CurrentPageTypeName. This Depedency prop is part of this custom Tab Control.

```
public static DependencyProperty CurrentPageTypeNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentPageTypeName", typeof(object), typeof(TabControlView));
    public object CurrentPageTypeName
    {
        get { return GetValue(CurrentPageTypeNameProperty) as object; }
        set { SetValue(CurrentPageTypeNameProperty, value); }
    }
```

In another view, where I am using the custom TabControl I then bind my property, with the actual name value, to CurrentPageTypeName property as seen below:

```
 <Views:TabControlView Grid.Row="0" Name="RunPageTabControl" 
                          TabItemsSource="{Binding RunPageTypeViewModels}"                              
                          SelectedTab="{Binding Converter={StaticResource debugConverter}}" 
                          CurrentPageTypeName="{Binding Path=RunPageName, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          TabContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource tabItemTemplateSelector}"  
                          SelectedIndex="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.SelectedTabIndex}"
                          ShowPageType="Hidden" >           
        <!--<Views:TabControlView.TabContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:RunPageTypeViewModel}">
                <RunViews:RunPageTypeView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Views:TabControlView.TabContentTemplate>-->

    </Views:TabControlView>
```

My problem is that nothing seems to be happening. It is grabbing its Content from the Itemsource, and not from my chained Dependency props. Is what I am trying even possible? If so, what have I done wrong.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: I can't see anything with an `x:Name` of `PageTabControl`, so I can quite imagine `ElementName="PageTabControl"` bindings will fail.  Also, may I ask what is grabbing its content from the 'Itemsource', and which 'Itemsource'?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something this is definitely possible. Here is a simplified working example.

User control with a dependency property named TestValue, containing a TextBox bound to this property:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.TestControl" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="TestControlName">
  <Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=TestControlName, Path=TestValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

A different view using this user control, binding the above mentioned dependency property to something:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:TestApp="clr-namespace:TestApp" Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350" Width="525">
  <StackPanel>
    <TestApp:TestControl TestValue="{Binding ElementName=SourceTextBox, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox Name="SourceTextBox" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

It sounds that the issue is somewhere in the part of the code you have not posted (e.g. wrong name used in Content binding).

Comment: although its an old thread, i got the same problem and the trick was to exaclty define the ElementName at the binding within the usercontrol. May there it is necessary because it is unclear what the datacontext might be when included within another control. The ElementName was not necessary within the Windows-include (second code snippet). Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already solved this yourself for the "`SelectedIndex`" property.  Just do the same thing for the "`CurrentPageType`" property i.e. use `RelativeSource`